# SQL Express 2008 R2 ClickOnce Prerequisite Install Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am currently working on a project where I am creating an installer application that installs all prerequisites required for my application to work locally on the clients machine.

When running my installer application it errors when installing SQL Express 2008 R2 with Advanced Services with the following error:

> Process exited with code -2067922356

I have tried to google the error, but have found nothing to solve my issue.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please off the firewall and antivirus for timebeing ? Once I had the same issue, I closed all the applications of Microsoft and switch off the windows's firewall and antivirus solved my problem.